# Callback when route is completely rendered

Tags: react-router, react-router-relay

The [`onUpdate`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/v1.0.0/docs/API.md#onupdate) callback of router seems to be called when rendering is initiated, is there any other way to call a function *after* all the components are rendered?

Something alike `ReactDOM.render` callback...

Comment: Did you find any for this?